# how to patch hole in interior chimney wall

Tags: brick, masonry, hole

I was recently removing plaster from the interior wall of my chimney and discovered a huge hole that had been patched by some drywall.

[image]

The chimney is still used to vent my furnace and water heater, but there are no active fireplaces anymore. I would like to patch this hole with brick. My currently plan is to take out the top and bottom bricks so that the hole becomes rectangular and then fill it with new bricks. Something like this:

[image]

Is this the correct way to approach this problem? Is there a simpler way to solve this while still filling the hole with brick? Are there tools and techniques for getting grout into the bricks like this?

Comment: It would help to know why you want to place bricks in as a patch. Is it because you have the intention to leave the chimney exposed? If this is the case are you able to source used distressed bricks of the same size and color?

Comment: To amplify his comment, if you do not need the visual appeal, you do not need to use brick at all. If you want the visual appeal, you'll want 4 bricks and maintain the step pattern used provided you can find similar brick

Comment: I do want to leave the brick exposed. I thought about the stair step visual aspect and it seemed hard, but I would be up for trying it. However, maybe the correct approach would be to patch with something besides brick and then build a shelf or something to cover the patch. If I were not to patch with brick what would I patch with?

Comment: All I can say is that unless you can match the look if the existing brick in terms of color and style any patch is going to stick out like a sore thumb. If you do decide to just patch and cover over somehow then you can just use mortar to fill in the hole. You could also break up and use parts of bricks in the opening if you can squeeze in enough of the mortar between then (which would be the same task if you were replacing whole bricks). There are some special tools for tuck pointing that could be useful for you for handling the mortar insertion.